# Cloth designer. Coloring of the layer

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

I try to make a cloth designer application within a structure based on layers just like in the Photoshop app.
I'm using an image with alpha channel and beneath it I'm placing div with different background colors. As a result, I expect changing the color of the image.
But I don't have any idea how to put over that image another layer using the same color.
When I try to repeat the same trick, it will fill extra space that I want to be transparent. In other words, I need to paint only the part of 
an image, leaving another part transparent.

I tried to use canvas for filling rgb(255,0,255) parts of image, but canvas is too slow.

```
<div class="preview_under">
  <div style="background: transparent url(images/main_template.png);" class="preview_middle">
    <div class="preview_over">
      <!-- override layers -->
      <div class="layer" style="background: url(images/blue.jpg);" data-name="modern" data-section="pocket">
        <img src="images/pocket_modern.jpg">
      </div>
      <!-- /override layers -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- color of the template -->
  <div class="fill" style="background: url(images/blue.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Graphical representation of the problem: [image]

UPD:
Thanks for all!
I solved my problem using canvas.
I tried [**globalCompositeOperation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) property and it works perfectly.
Demo is [here](http://shelimov.me/fi.js/demo.html).

Comment: Only theory kills my eyes, can you share some code? or some examples of what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody!
I solved my problem through the canvas.
I just used [**globalCompositeOperation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) property.

```
..
ctx.drawImage(original, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.drawImage(fill, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.drawImage(border, 0, 0);
...
```

Demo is [**here**](http://shelimov.me/fi.js/demo.html).

Answer (score 3):

A canvas should be fast, maybe the slowness has to do with algorithm in use.

But, if you tried with a canvas, it means that you are targeting modern browsers. So probably SVG will work :)

Changing the color with SVG is very easy (see http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/kkxP3/):

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="pocket" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('pocket').style.fill = 'red';
```

You can overlay the cloth parts in a layer, and use a tool like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/) to draw them (plus you can setup the background image on the SVG using the visual editor, so you don't need to do the overlay by hand :) )

Other possible solutions are:

- Have a predefined set of colors, and a PNG with "sprites" for each variation, so you only change the background offset on each color change. (good: doesn't requires anything special, and will work with all browsers; bad: the color variations are fixed, creating those sprites is time consuming).
- Use the canvas to change the picture (look for issues in the slow algorithm). Then you can use `toDataURL` to cache an image generated by the canvas. In that way when the user changes the colors you use the cached image if it already exists. (good: you don't need to edit the pictures by hand; bad: more complex to code)

Comment: But how to change color of the part of png image via svg? Will I need to redraw all images to vector?

Comment: Sadly you can't change a raster image in that way, you'll need to have the vector SVG image to do that. If the color options is limited, using PNG sprites is the simplest thing to do: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ (you'll have to create the sprites, or you can use a PNG file for each color).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, with limited browser support, but very easy to implement, is to set the images with only a color but having the posibility to use saturation and luminance changes.

then apply

```
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(xdeg);
```

To change to any color.

Doing the same, but with an svg filter, can have more support

[a silly demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7zGY7/)

Comment: Wow, It's really nice filter, but it's work only in lastest browsers.